# Evaluating computed code that accesses locally scoped variables

Tags: javascript, scope, eval

I'm trying to create a function that returns a callback, which when called, will access the **callers local scope parameters**.

Consider the following code:

```js
function caller() {
    let param = "original scope param.";
    let wrapped = callee();

    eval(wrapped.toString())(); // Works
    wrapped(); // Doesn't work
}

function callee() {
    return () => eval("console.log('Im accessing ' + param)");
}

caller()
```

calling `eval` in the `caller` function works, but I don't control that function, so I can't make it `eval` my output.

If I could access the Scope Chain, my problem would be solved, but I didn't find anything that does that. Any help would be appreciated, even if the solution is very dirty.

Comment: long story short: it's not possible. If `caller` doesn't expose this variable, then you **can not** access it from the outside.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! i'll provide the larger context: i'm trying to write a function that receives a callback, changes some code inside the callback, and then evaluates and executes the modified callback. the problem is that the callback still accessed some variables from where it was defined, and eval doesn't keep the closure obviously. i figured that if i could return the modified function back to the caller, the caller would be able to call it and it'll access the local variables. apparently it's impossible :(